# Sublime Text 3 Anaconda Build System Fails

Tags: python, sublimetext3, build-system

I used to use the Spyder IDE that came with Anaconda installation, but want to switch to Sublime Text recently.
I created the file "AnacondaNew.sublime-build" as follows:

```
{
"cmd": ["C:\\Users\\u22y33\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

And then, when I tried to build a simple .py file with import statements, I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\u22y33\PythonProjects_Spyder\MonthlyReport\ButtonCallBack.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\u22y33\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\u22y33\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

I can still run the .py files in Spyder perfectly fine. Do you guys have any idea where it went wrong? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you have to add the anaconda folders manually to the system path of windows.

Another option is to re-install anaconda and select the options during the installation (install for all users, and add system path).